# Hibernate - SQL annotation @Where clause with multiple LIKE operator on the same column name

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-like, hibernate-annotations

I want to add one or more LIKE operator in the below @Where clause for the same column name. But, if i add LIKE with OR/AND operator am not getting the exact result.
  How i can simplify this scenario to get the Exact value.

Please find my code below.

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause="name NOT LIKE '%long%' AND name LIKE '%description'")
private List<ProductAttr> productAttr;
public List<ProductAttr> getProductAttr() {
    return productAttr;
}

public void setProductAttr(List<ProductAttr> productAttr) {
    this.productAttr = productAttr;
}
```

If i use AND Operator

```
@Where(clause="name NOT LIKE '%long%' AND name LIKE '%description' AND name 
LIKE '%source%'")
```

It will gives null pointer exception for some records.

If i use OR Operator

```
    @Where(clause="name NOT LIKE '%long%' AND name LIKE '%description' OR 
    name LIKE '%source%'")
```

Am missing some values here.

What will be the best approach to solve this scenario.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Where(clause="name NOT LIKE '%long%' AND name LIKE '%description' AND name LIKE '%source%'")
```

Above query means each record of `name` column `must not contain long word and must contain description word and must contain source word`

```
@Where(clause="name NOT LIKE '%long%' AND name LIKE '%description' OR name LIKE '%source%'")
```

Above query means each record of `name` column `must not contain long word but must contain either description or source word`

Hence the resultSet will differ for both the queries.

Comment: Is that any other way to combine both cases together. Means, query result should not miss any results if something is not available.